# Trouble installing Plugin Builder

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation

I am having trouble installing the Plugin Builder plugin. I am installing it through the plugin manager in QGIS 2.18.0, and getting the following error message:

> Plugin installation failed: Failed to unzip the plugin package. Probably it's broken or missing from the repository. You may also want to make sure that you have write permission to the plugin directory: C:/Users/_myUsername_/.qgis2/python/plugins

I definitely have write permission to this folder, I have tried rebooting and reinstalling QGIS to no avail. I am running the program as administrator.

Since there is no other way (as far as I can tell) of installing the Plugin Builder, can anyone help me trouble shoot this issue?

---

For reference this is actually true for all Plugins installed through the Plugin manager.

Comment: I see your name has accented characters, is that also the case in your windows user name?

Comment: @SteveKay thanks, but through the years I've learned to remove all oddities from my usernames, the hard way :)

Answer (score 4):

I managed to find another way to install the Plugin Builder: downloading it off http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pluginbuilder/ and extracting the .zip to the folder mentioned above, then restarting QGIS and loading the plugin in the plugin manager. I wasn't, however, able to resolve the initial issue.